# Richfaces - Get Element By Id

Tags: richfaces

We are using [Richfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richfaces) in one of our projects.

I need to focus the element dynamically on some user action.
The issue here is I only have the id ([JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) specific id that I give to element.)

For example: for `h:inputText` I use it as

```
<h:inputText id="userNameInputBox" value="<<some binding>>/>
```

and this input box is embedded in separate form. When I include the input box in form, the id of the input box will be: `formName:userNameInputBox (<<formName>>:<<elementId>>)`

I will be re-using the input box in multiple [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)s. That means, I do not know the parent form in which I will include the input box.

Now, I need to focus() the input box. Currently I am not able to do this as I do not have the actual generated id (`<<formname>>:<<elementId>>`) but I only have the JSF specific id I gave.

How can I make focusing the element work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the RichFaces tag function `#{rich:clientId( JSF_ID )}` to get the appropriate client id for a component. If you need the element inside the DOM tree, you can get it directly with  `#{rich:element( JSF_ID )}`

Example: 
`onclick="#{rich:element('userNameInputBox')}.focus()"`

I believe you need RichFaces 3.2.0 or higher for this to work.

The documentation on [Richfaces JS Interaction functions](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#JavascriptInteractions)

Comment: Is there an alternate for primefaces to accomplish this ? Thanks!