# Richfaces component id in form - css

Tags: css, richfaces

I have a component inside a form:

```
<a:form id="myform">
   <a:somecomponent id="comp">
</a:form>
```

and a huge css file, which attaches some style to the component with id "comp".

However, this does not work, as in the rendered html page, the components name becomes "myform:comp".

How can I prevent this? Using myform:comp in css does not seem to work :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `prependId="false"` to form tag.

```
<a:form id="myform" prependId="false">
   <a:somecomponent id="comp">
</a:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the richfaces functions detailed [here](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/12/richfaces-built-in-client-functions/). `#{rich:clientId(‘comp’)}` can be used in this case.

*Edit: also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648507/richfaces-get-element-by-id/1679536#1679536)*

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found up till now is not to use the id, but the style class, and replace all of the occurences of #comp in the css file with .comp:

```
<a:form id="myform">
   <a:somecomponent styleClass="comp">
</a:form>
```

However, I don't consider this as a 'clean' solution...